# Adding disks to add more space to RAID 1+0 array

Tags: linux, raid, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 server running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. During the installation I had setup RAID 1+0(which I believe is same as RAID 10?):

hpssacli ctrl all show config
Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 00143803246ED20)
   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)
      logicaldrive 1 (838.1 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)

```
  physicaldrive 1I:2:1 (port 1I:box 2:bay 1, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:2:2 (port 1I:box 2:bay 2, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:2:3 (port 1I:box 2:bay 3, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:2:4 (port 1I:box 2:bay 4, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:2:5 (port 2I:box 2:bay 5, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:2:6 (port 2I:box 2:bay 6, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
```

SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model SRCv8x6G) 380  (WWID: 500143803246ED2F)

The server is now running out of space and I would like to add more disks to it. Is it possible to do this without any down time? Can I just replace one disk at a time with a higher capacity one and once I am done replacing them all, just expand the file system(not sure which command to use here)?

If this is not possible, what are my options?

Answer (score 1):

You can add physical disks to the array if you wish. That can be completed without downtime. You can also replace the drives with larger disks one-by-one.

This is all covered in the [HP Smart Array Controllers reference guide](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03909334)...

Also see:

[HP RAID array - hpacucli](https://serverfault.com/questions/451055/hp-raid-array-hpacucli/451057#451057)

[What are the good ways to migrate a RAID array to bigger disks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/371117/what-are-the-good-ways-to-migrate-a-raid-array-to-bigger-disks/371131#371131)

[Reconfigure HP Smart Array RAID 50 with larger drives](https://serverfault.com/questions/471984/reconfigure-hp-smart-array-raid-50-with-larger-drives/472062#472062)

[Extend RAID 1 (HP SmartArray P410i) running Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/497167/extend-raid-1-hp-smartarray-p410i-running-linux/497233#497233)

[Extend RAID 5 to use unused space and add additional disks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/414234/extend-raid-5-to-use-unused-space-and-add-additional-disks/414258#414258)

Comment: Thanks! I think I will have to replace the drives with larger disks one-by-one.  because we only have 2 free bays on the server and that's not going to be enough. 

The question is once I replace them all do I have to manually re-configure HP Smart Array or will it be detected and configured automatically so that I only have to resize the LVM manually?

Comment: Read the manual or any of the links I posted for details.